# How to test Phonegap applications in Eclipse ADT bundle

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, adt

I have Download the Eclipse ADT Bundle and i am able to Launch the Eclipse and Can see the Option to develop Android Application.Now as I want to Develop PhoneGap Application so have Downloaded that too.Now through the Command Promt i have created a phonegap application Directory successfully.After this i Opened this PhoneGap application Directory folder into the Eclipse .Till here everything is fine . As this is Hello World Application it is working fine in the emulator and I can see the output but as it is very slow and as i do not have any mobile device to connect to the IDE and test the application i googled out and got to know about the `Chrome Ripple` Which i have installed as Extension in my Chrome Browser.`Chrome Ripple` is a debugging tool in which we can see the output very fast on the browser itself, no need of any Emulator or Physical Device .

But the problem is that we need to have a localhost server installed into the Eclipse IDE to run the PhoneGap HTML5 pages into a localhost server and then test it on `Ripple` but i am not seeing any way to add Any server in this eclipse version ..

Please help me how can i add any localhost server into this Eclipse ADT Bundle to test PhoneGap application..
Thanks..

Comment: You mean access localhost server like xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have KitKat 4.4+ it is a lot easier to use chrome for debug.

Type un chrome:

chrome://inspect

You can connect to you mobile and inspect html structure and debug without any server.

[image]

Other way is to add browser platform in Cordova that is available from last version (4.0). It is intended for debug into browser similar way as ripple mocking all plugins.

Comment: OK..Is it possible to add any web server into Eclipse that come along with the ADT Bundle

Comment: You do not need any web server... Just deploy in a 4.4+ device connected ant you can inspect inside html page